# How to call setinterval in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I am trying to call `setinterval` function in jQuery, but it is giving error

`Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'setinterval' is undefined`

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            setInterval(function () {alert("HELLO WORLD!");}, 300);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
//HTML code is here.
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Works for me! http://jsfiddle.net/NsVGa/ (time changed so it can be easily stopped).

Comment: the code you shared is correct, I think we should see your whole code, if it's possible.

Comment: @ocanal: I updated my code and I also provided error screen shot. But strange why negative vote? I am really facing this error.

Comment: Is your script reference really `src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"`? If so, I think you need to prefix the URI with `http:`.

Comment: @halfer : I try it but still same error.

Comment: Is that the *EXACT* code you are using?

Comment: @epascarello: yes EXACT code and myself also surprise why this code is not working?

Comment: @halfer: Using a protocol-less URL works fine as long as you're not loading the page from a file:/// URL (in which case the protocol-less URL tries to load jQuery from that path locally instead of from the Google CDN). For more info: http://encosia.com/cripple-the-google-cdns-caching-with-a-single-character/

Comment: Have you tried `window.setInterval()`? Have you tried `setInterval()` without the jQuery code? (For the code shown you don't actually need a document.ready since you aren't interacting with the document...)

Comment: Are you cached with a bad version of the file. Clear the cache.

Comment: I don't have IE9 to check this, but doesn't it show the exact line where the error is triggered in the developer tools javascript console?

Comment: I have tried so many things and now it is working in IE9 also, I don't know which step solve the problem. But it was a strange problem. Any way thanks everybody who spend his time to solve this problem. THANKS!

Answer (score 4):

The screenshot shows that you are trying to use "setinterval", that is without the capital "i", which is a mistake (javascript is case-sensitive). Either it is not the exact code you are using, either there is another piece of code somewhere who does call it.

Comment: It is EXACT code I am using and it is working fine in Firefox. If "i" is the issue then it should not run in Firefox.